# Android restart AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having some trouble restarting an `AsyncTask` after I try to reopen the activity.

When I first open the activity I call this to start the `AsyncTask` which works the very first time.

```
myTask connectedTask;
connectedTask = new myTask();
connectedTask.execute();

public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
        //Increase timer and wait here in a loop
        System.out.println("ASYNC TASK STARTING!");
        return IsSocketConnected();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Something you want to do when done?
        System.out.println("ASYNC TASK DONE!");

        // if it was connected successfully 
        if(result == 1) {
            // remove the progress bar
            proBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Discover available devices settings and create buttons
            CreateButtons(btnList);
        }
    }
}

IsSocketConnected(); // checks for a bluetooth connections to be done.
```

When I go back to previous activity and try to start that activity again I can't get the `AsyncTask` to start again.

I read that as long as I create a new instance of the `AsyncTask` I should be to restart those tasks.

Is there something else that I should be doing?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean that you can't get it to work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Sorry Ted, that was a bad choice of words. I meant I can't get it to restart. I get no error codes nothing It doesnt go to doInBackground

Comment: Is this code in `onCreate`? `onResume`? Agree with @TedHopp, more information is needed.

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend abandoning `AsyncTask` in this case for `Loader`s (which are available through the v4 support library).

Comment: Is there something in the `myTask` code that would prevent it from running a second time (such as dependence on instance variables of the enclosing class)? Are you sure that `doInBackground` is not called at all after the first time through? Perhaps you could post the code for `myTask` (including at least the constructor and `doInBackground`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all your comments they helped a lot. I decided to do away with the AsyncTask. I ended using a normal runnable Thread and using Handlers to post messages back to the UI thread. here is the code:

```
        // Start thread here only for IsSocketConnected
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                //Add your code here..
                IsSocketConnected();

            }
        }).start();


// handler that deals with updating UI
public Handler myUIHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.what == Bluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            //Update UI here...
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");




            // Discover available devices settings and create buttons
            CreateButtons(btnList);

        } else if(msg.what == Bluetooth.STATE_NONE) {

            Log.d(TAG, "NOT Connected");
        }
```

}

```
// in the IsSocketConnected() I call this 
Message theMessage = myUIHandler.obtainMessage(Bluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED);
myUIHandler.sendMessage(theMessage);//Sends the message to the UI handler.
```

This is working so far. Thank you again. Hope this helps someone

Comment: The benefit of `AsyncTask` is that it runs tasks on a thread pool. It's more efficient than creating a new thread every time. Of course you could always run this on your own thread pool.

Answer (score 5):

Good that OP found a solution, but answering for future readers;

You can add a method, like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
     public static MyTask loadTextDataTask;
     
     //... methods

     public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         //... methods

         public void selfRestart() {
             loadTextDataTask = new MyTask();
         }
     }
```

}

Then you can use it from any other class, like:

```
MainActivity.loadTextDataTask.selfrestart();
```

> **Note** that there is no real way to restart existing instnace, and even if we call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`, the second call to `AsyncTask.execute()` throws
>
> ```
> IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed
> ```

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, you can simply create a new instance and execute it to start again.  I wonder what function you are starting the task in?  It would probably be a good idea to start it in your `onResume()` function, just in case the activity is not destroyed before it comes back to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in `onResume()` like:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    myTask connectedTask = new myTask();
    connectedTask.execute();
}
```

It should create a new object when you resume back to your `Activity`.  You didn't post it, but were probably creating the object in `onCreate()` which is only run once.

My recommendation for handling `Socket` connections is to just subclass `Thread` itself.

Comment: Careful... you need to add the @Override annotation to your function there. Also, just to clarify, onCreate() is called every time the activity is created. So is onResume, the difference is the activity has to die before onCreate can get called again. This is essentially the same answer I posted 20 minutes ago...

Comment: Depending on what the async task is doing, this could be a very poor strategy. `onResume` is called whenever the activity resumes from being paused, which can happen many times while the activity is alive. (For instance, pulling down a notification, taking a call, etc.)

Comment: Good catch with the Override.  onCreate() is called every time the activity is created, but it seems like he is having a problem with making the activity active again which would just call onResume().  I also recommended that he just use a Thread for his connection.

Comment: true, what you need to do, is check to see if the asynctask is running, and if it is not running, start a new one. still ok to do in onResume

Comment: @TedHopp That is true.  It looks like he is just trying to see if his Socket is connected or not (and whether to make a connection) each time he resumes to the Activity though.  Seems like it would be harmless to check in each onResume(), but we don't know what his IsSocketConnected() method looks like so can't be sure.

Comment: hopefully it is pretty lightweight.. but it sounds like that is managed by his asynctask, if the task is running, is it safe to say that thread is managing the connection? I guess that is a question for  him to answer haha

Answer (score 0):

Better, use OnPostExecute, to trigger a new instance of the task. It will fire if the task is completed. But use a boolean to prevent it to trigger itself everytime

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

if(someboolean==true) { 
                            new instance of task;
                            instance.execute;
                someboolean=false;
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The developer website says

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Starting with HONEYCOMB, AsyncTask uses a single Executor by default for executing tasks, which then runs one task at a time. It means that if you call myTask.execute() after you have already called it on any activity (**anywhere on main thread**), the 2nd call will wait to invoke the doInBackground method until the first task has completed. If your IsSocketConnected() method doesn't return immediately it will block any doInBackground() invocations after calling AsyncTask.execute() method again anywhere on the main thread, until the current Task completes.

If your isSocketConnected() uses any blocking operations such as wait() or Thread.sleep(), you can work around it by calling **myTask.cancel(true)** in the onDestroy() callback to your activity, which will throw an InterruptedException. Just make sure that you catch the InterruptedException in a place that will cause the thread to exit the doInBackground method.

You can also do a workaround by using a custom **ThreadPoolExecutor** and calling the AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor) method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
connectedTask = new myTask();
connectedTask.execute();

Simply use:
newconnectTask.execute();
Use it where u exactly want to restart the task!!